# Clustering with unknown number of clusters in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have a very large dataset (about 3.5M) of text messages. I am using tf-idf vector to represent each message in this dataset. I want to cluster the messages of the same topic together and I don't know the actual clusters or even the number of them.

So I searched a little and found that Optics, DBSCAN, or HDBSCAN can do this job but there is no implementation of them is spark ml or `mllib`. according to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html) In spark `mllib` there are implementations of `K-means`, `Gaussian mixture`, `Power iteration clustering (PIC)`, `Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)`, `Bisecting k-means` and `Streaming k-means`.

So my problem is, all of them need K as an input and I don't have it. Is there any clustering algorithm implemented in Spark that find the number of clusters on its own?

Comment: Sounds more like a `groupBy topoic` requirement than a clustering requirement. Why do you want to solve this as a clustering problem? What would be the dimensions?

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa so is there a way to group these dataset by unknown topics ? the dimensions of tf-idf vector is very high and the vectors are very sparse

Answer (score 1):

Got a little bit too long for a comment. I'll try to explain it here.

Do you have the data on which topic a message belongs? Then you can simply do a group by that topic to group all the messages with similar topics.

That's one thing. And if you are trying to derive topics (K) from the dataset itself, then you need little more statistics to build a sound feature set to cluster them. Then you can come to a conclusion on K by varying it and find the best K with minimal error. There is a famous method called `elbow method`.

Check this out. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-determine-the-optimal-value-of-k-in-k-means-clustering/#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20popular%20method,fewer%20elements%20in%20the%20cluster](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-determine-the-optimal-value-of-k-in-k-means-clustering/#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20popular%20method,fewer%20elements%20in%20the%20cluster).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No I dont have topics of messages and its exactly what I want. I think elbow is not good enough for my problem because the number of topics may be very high

Comment: Well, you can have k from 1 to number of data points (n)  you have. I haven't done this but just a thought. How about using divide and conquer? Starts with let's say k=100, n/2, n/4, 3n/4.

Comment: number of data points is 3.5M. I dont think this is the right solution

Comment: Depends on your spark cluster. The number of data points might not be a significant factor for performance. But the size is. Sorry, I couldn't help you as expected.